# WPF change aligment of label and Viewbox

Tags: wpf, xaml, label, viewbox

So i have a label in a `viewbox` so when the application scales the label will also scale. However the user what to choose to `AutoScale via Viewbox` or `No autoscaling` and set the properties for the label itself.

So far i got this:

```
<Viewbox Name="vb">
    <Label
        Name="lblText"
        Width="{Binding ElementName=Sign, Path=ActualWidth}"
        Height="{Binding ElementName=Sign, Path=ActualHeight}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="{Binding TextAlignment}"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
        Background="Transparent"
        Content="{Binding ObjectName}"
        FontFamily="{Binding Font_Family}"
        FontSize="{Binding FontSize}"
        Foreground="{Binding FontColor}" />
</Viewbox>
```

Now to get the label AutoSize i have to set the Width and Height to Auto. However when i do this i cannot longer use the `HorizontalContentAlignment` because the label is the size of the text. When bound to the viewbox size then i can use it but the `AutoSize` doesn't work.

I was thinking about a event then when the user changes the `` then a event will fire where i can set the properties of the viewbox and label in code.

So in short i'm looking for a way to create a textholding object that can AutoSize or set by hand.

Comment: what about a TextBlock?

Comment: Tested it and got same result, maybe you can post an example of how you got it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply set the `Stretch` property of the Viewbox by a DataTrigger, e.g. on a boolean `Autoscale` property:

```
<Viewbox>
    <Viewbox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Viewbox">
            <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="None"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Autoscale}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Uniform"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Viewbox.Style>

    ...
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: DOH...!!, that i didn't think about this... Works exactly how i wanted, thanks!